# How to listen for map expiring & turning white the next day?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

So I have a web-based MapBox map that loads and renders perfectly. However when I leave the tab open in my browser and come back the next day, the map has gone completely white and all the layers are no longer rendered. The page has to be refreshed.

I've been trying endlessly to figure how I can capture this unloading/expiring event. I've added listeners for on `error`,  `remove` events and more. I'm not even clear if it's the api token or the map or the source Style that is expiring.

I've poured over the docs. I'm pretty sure this even happens to MapBox's own Studio application so I'm starting to think I need to set a 12 hour timer and just refresh the page or something.

Does anyone have an event I can listen for or a recommended approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `webglcontextlost` was the winner. I don't actually think that this represents the MapBox expiring issue, because it is related to the HTML canvas that the map is drawn on. It's a symptom that triggers when the greater problem happens. But so far it's the only thing I can listen for to capture this occurrence. Will update this answer if I find a better way.

Remains to be seen if the location refresh will get rid of the blank map problem.

```
map.on('webglcontextlost', function () {
    console.log('Map webglcontextlost event triggered.');

    // Force a refresh to the server.
    window.location.reload();           
});
```

Documentation: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map.event:webglcontextlost